# conexão localDB visual estudio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Boa noite, eu baixei eu sistema de scola em vb da internet , mas quando vou testar o aplicativo da erro na conexao do sql server.  ele ja veio configurado , eu ate joguei o arquivo .mdf para dentro da pasta como esta na configuração de conexão
nao sei oque fazer, me ajudem por favor
estou usando visual studio 13

```html
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Sistema_Colegio.My.MySettings.COLEGIOConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB=|DataDirectory|\bin\Debug\COLEGIO.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem o SQL Server LocalDB instalado na máquina? O arquivo `\bin\Debug\COLEGIO.mdf` existe no diretório do projeto?

Comment: não tenho ele instalado não amigo.  e sim esta no diretório!

Answer (score 0):

[Faça o download do Microsoft SQL Server Express](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799012). Nas opções de instalação, marque a opção "LocalDB".

Feito isso, teste novamente.

Comment: amigo instalei o LocalDB. porém eu tenho que instalar o sql express também  ? se sim estou baixando a atualização do meu windows para poder instalar e vejo se funciona ok obg pela atenção

Comment: Não precisa instalar o SQL Express inteiro. Apenas a parte do LocalDB. De qualquer forma, é interessante ter a ferramenta inteira se você resolver gerenciar seu banco de dados com mais recursos.